# How to modify or override Main page content block in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

I had wasted my 2 days but unable to find a way that how to modify or override the main page content block in drupal 7. Please help me.
[image]
I want to edit this main page content block.

Comment: I want to modify main page content which is present under blocks.

Comment: 1) Clarify by editing, not commenting. 2) So, it sounds my guess was right, wasn't it? Try solutions from there, play with them, if that's not what you want, tell us what have you tried and how it differs from your needs.

Comment: I am just asking that as there are ways to modify custom content type i.e node--[content_type].tpl.php, then is there a way to modify main page content block? I just want that e.g. I only show title not body, then is there a way to do so?

Comment: [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/98138/edit)

Comment: you should edit your post and provide more information as suggested by @Mołot.

Comment: The edit that has been done has done little to explain better what the question is. I don't think anyone was asking about which block the question was about. Still voting close.